# How do I yield an iterable of different types?

Tags: python

Originally my code was:

```
def yieldTwice(iterable):
    x = 0
    while x < len(iterable):
        y = 0
        while y < 2:
            yield iterable[x]
            y += 1
        x += 1
```

However it resulted in an error when the iterable is a generator:

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

So I switched to:

```
def yieldTwice(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        y = 0
        while y < 2:
            yield iterable[x]
            y += 1
```

However, that gives the error:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: just use ``yield x`` instead of ``yield iterable[x]`` in your second method?

Comment: Just `yield x` in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate the object directly, don't use the result as an index. It literally is the object you want. Try this:

```
def yieldTwice(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        y = 0
        while y < 2:
            yield x
            y += 1
```

BTW, you can get rid of the loop (in the first place, you should use `for _ in range(2)` instead of `while`, but anyway...):

```
def yieldTwice(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        yield x
        yield x
```